# Propagate event to all controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I'm using the following piece of code, for documentation, error handling and/or logging. It's saves an image of the UserControl or Form when I click it pressing Control+Alt+Shift:

```
  public Image GetImage()
  {
     Bitmap oBmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
     this.DrawToBitmap(oBmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, oBmp.Width, oBmp.Height));
     return (Image)oBmp;
  }

  protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnMouseDown(e);

     bool bControl = false;
     bool bShift = false;
     bool bAlt = false;

     bControl = (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control;
     bShift = (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift;
     bAlt = (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt;

     if (bControl && bShift && bAlt)
     {
        GetImage().Save(this.Name.TimedLocalFileName("png"), ImageFormat.Png);
     }
  }
```

Right now, I'm coding it in every UserControl, in the base form and so. It's easy to do because I'm using a code Snippet. But it has obvious setbacks.

1. The same piece of code in a lot of places (maintainability); and
2. Works only when I click on the base control and not it's childs (if an UserControl has a Label, this doesn't works.

I've been for a few days analyzing GlobalHooks (mostly here: [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C), but my head is not helping me.

Any suggestion will be very much appreciated.

**Note:** TimedLocalFileName is an extension method that returns a String in format `<ControlName>_<Culture>_<YYYYMMDD>_<HHMMSS>.<FileExtension>`

Comment: You could expose and generate a public event when a MouseDown is raised (and all the expected keys are pressed). You can have a specialized class subscribe to these events (with a single handler) and use the `sender` object to determine  which control raised the event and act accordingly. Btw, the `Control.DrawToBitmap()` method should actually paint the UC'c internal controls and their content (except RichTextBox controls, a *special* case).

Comment: If not (for some reason), you can try [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57257205/7444103).

Comment: Create a `UserControl` as base of all other user controls. In the base user control redirect `MouseDown` event of all child controls to the control, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50886066/3110834). Then handle click event of the control and run your custom logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a base [`UserControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and name it `BaseUserControl` and derive all your user control from `BaseUserControl` then you can put all the logic inside the base user control.

Inside the `BaseUserControl`, using a recursive method, handle `MouseDown` event of all child controls and redirect them to [`OnMouseDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onmousedown?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) of `this`, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50886066/3110834).

Override [`OnHanldeCrated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onhandlecreated?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and call that recursive method to wire up events.

Here is the base control:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class BaseUserControl : UserControl
{
    void WireMouseEvents(Control container)
    {
        foreach (Control c in container.Controls)
        {
            c.MouseDown += (s, e) =>
            {
                var p = PointToThis((Control)s, e.Location);
                OnMouseDown(new MouseEventArgs(e.Button, e.Clicks, p.X, p.Y, e.Delta));
            };
            WireMouseEvents(c);
        };
    }
    Point PointToThis(Control c, Point p)
    {
        return PointToClient(c.PointToScreen(p));
    }
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        if (Control.ModifierKeys == (Keys.Control | Keys.Alt | Keys.Shift))
            MessageBox.Show("Handled!");
        // Your custom logic
    }
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        WireMouseEvents(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work like a charm! Let me test it a little more and will mark it as the answer. Thank you very very much

Comment: No problem. Take your time on testing it and let me know if you find any issue. I think it's addressing both issues which is mentioned in the question.

Comment: I seems like depending on the order of invocation of all ``OnHandleCreated`` handlers, you might subscribe several times to the same `MouseDown` event, no? For example, if a control ``A`` contains ``B`` which contains ``C``, and if you call ``WireMouseEvents`` on ``A`` then ``B`` then ``C`` you 'll end up subscribing way too many times.

Comment: @CorentinPane `WireMouseEvents` is called just in the base control so in all normal scenarios I cannot see any problem. If you are talking about cases that a derived user control is hosting another derived user control, then the problem can be fixed easily in the foreach loop by checking type of the control.

Comment: I also couldn't find any problem using `OnHandleCreated`. Just in case that you had any doubt about it, as an alternative implement `ISupportInitialize` interface and call the wire function id `EndInit`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei. This piece of code is gold! At least for me. I have it now in only 3 places for any solution: the BaseUserControl, my BaseForm and the solution form because it does something different. I cannot thank you enough. When you are in Uruguay, beers on me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**Answering issue 1**

> The same piece of code in a lot of places (maintainability)

It's not always applicable but if you find yourself using this behavior a lot, you could inherit from `UserControl` to create `BitmapExportUserControl` and put `Image GetImage()` and `override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)` in this class instead, and make all your custom controls that need this behavior inherit from `BitmapExportUserControl`.

Another way could to perform the bitmap export from your `Form` itself, and have your `Form` subscribe to all the `MouseDown` events of all its children `Control` objects.

**Answering issue 2**

> Works only when I click on the base control and not it's childs

As far as I know, there is no built-in "up" event propagation (or bubbling) in WinForms as there is in WPF for example. A solution could be to expose an event that can be raised by all `UserControl` in your application when there is a `MouseDown` event on them. Your code would become:

```cs
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    GlobalMouseDown.RaiseGlobalMouseDownEvent(this, e);
}
```

and you would have your main `Form` subscribe to this `GlobalMouseDown.GlobalMouseDownEvent` and perform the checks and bitmap export.

This is functionally equivalent to having a public method `HandleMouseDown` in some `GlobalMouseDown` class that would be called by all your `UserControl` `MouseDownEventHandlers`. The code in each `UserControl` would become:

```cs
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    GlobalMouseDown.HandleMouseDown(this, e);
}
```

and you would do your checks and bitmap export in this method.

Comment: This make total sense. I'm trying other answer and see what happens. Anyway, thank you sou much